# Modal box height and overflow

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have some problem with my modal box. On overflow, the text goes beyond the block. What can i do with this? Also i want to remove scrolling main page when modal is open. Is there any way exept hide overflow-y? Here is  [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u8Ldwc2z/1/) where u can see my problem.

```js
$("#reviewBtn").click(function () {
  $("#reviewModal").show()
});
$(".close").click(function () {
  $("#reviewModal").hide()
});
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.modal-content {
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 2%;
}

.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="reviewModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Text </p>
    ttt
    </div>
        </div>

  <button  class = "reviews-btn" id="reviewBtn">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add class in `body` when modal is open and `overflow:hidden` in that class

```js
$("#reviewBtn").click(function () {
  $("#reviewModal").show();
  $('body').addClass('modal-open');
});
$(".close").click(function () {
  $("#reviewModal").hide();
  $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
});
```

```css
body.modal-open {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  padding-top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.modal-content {
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #abff3b;
  margin: auto;
  /*width: 100%;
  height: 100%;*/
  padding: 2%;
}

.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="reviewModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.<br/> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum<br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. <br/>
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. <br/> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.  <br/>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum </p>
    </div>
        </div>

  <button  class = "reviews-btn" id="reviewBtn">Click</button>
```

Comment: sorry fot another question, but i need  modal box to take full height and width except padding-top. How can i make it withpit content height and width 100%?

Comment: In the above snippet, modal take full height and width of the screen

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way if you set by modal open the `body` of your page to `display: fixed`.

```
$("#reviewBtn").click(function () {
  $("#reviewModal").show();
  $('body').css({'display': 'fixed'});
});
$(".close").click(function () {
  $("#reviewModal").hide();
  $('body').css({'display': 'block'});
});
```

Comment: @lortshi  i am trying, but it doesn;t work

Comment: I realized my solution was just one part your question, to fix the underneath body scroll if the modal is opened. The complete and nice solution is made by @Minal Chauhan.

Comment: @lortshi I forget something too. I was think that its page scroll cause of overflow bg-color, but its modal. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You just probably need to give fixed height to p tag inside modal

```
.modal-content > p {
     height: 40vh;
     overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Its a good way, but i must not use fixed height

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#reviewBtn").click(function () {
  $("#reviewModal").show();
  $("body").addClass("overflow-hidden");
});
$(".close").click(function () {
  $("#reviewModal").hide();
  $("body").removeClass("overflow-hidden");
});
```

// css

```
body.overflow-hidden {
    overflow:hidden !important;
}
    
.modal-content {
    height:auto;
}
.modal {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```